# Recursive and non-recursive ACLs in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I am thinking about a current problem - which always happens when you have a search on a tree together with per-node ACLs - if the user requests a paginated result, I would sometimes have to retrieve a raw result, filter against the ACLs, and if I don't have enough results, i have to search again ... until I have enough results.

Wouldn't it be nicer to be able to do this in one go?

Given this (I am skipping indexes for brevity):

```
CREATE DATABASE `test`;

CREATE TABLE `acl` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `entry_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `principal_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `recursive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `permission` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_entry_has_acl_idx` (`entry_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_entry_has_acl` FOREIGN KEY (`entry_id`) REFERENCES `entry` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `entry` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Would this statement (skipping any actual search conditions):

```
SELECT 
    e.* 
FROM 
    entry e JOIN acl a JOIN entry e2 ON 
        ((
              e.id = a.entry_id 
            AND 
              a.recursive=0 
          ) OR (
              a.entry_id = e2.id
            AND 
              e.path LIKE CONCAT(e2.path,'%') 
            AND
              a.recursive=1

        )) 
        AND 
          a.principal_id in ("K") 
        AND 
          a.permission IN ("READ","WRITE")
    GROUP BY e.id;
```

be the statement I am looking for? Can you spot any obvious improvements and/or mistakes? I am a slightly unhappy about the CONCAT statement in there ... is there a way to avoid this?

EDIT: ids are UUIDs, and the "path" field would contain the parent IDs all the way up, as in:

```
 c83eff41-dec8-45fb-94ef-6e3f380ebcec.1db333d9-995e-4e24-af8a-da2faf962060.dd71fd12-c975-4f33-bf0e-2df9da312bcd
```

Comment: You should have the directory separator character before `%`, so you don't match paths that are similar but not nested.

Comment: @barmar you're a little bit right, but I am using UUIDs, and i am using the path in UUIDs, not by name. and they're fixed length anyways. so i don't really expect any collisions there. i'll be adding this constraint to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, my first optimization would be to have the path (what i did do with concat) in the ACL table, including or not including the wildcard (depending on the recursive flag)

```
foo bar recursive  entry_path

... ... 1          ID1.ID2.ID3% 
... ... 0          ID1.ID2.ID3
```

so i can join with a simple LIKE

```
.... FROM entry e, entry_acl a ON e.
```